# CSS Float relative to previous elements

Tags: css, css-float, multiple-columns

Is there a way of allowing an element to float based on the dimensions of the elements that preceded it rather than inline to where the element is called.

Take this for example. Column One floats left, whilst two floats right. Based on this code however, Column Two will float relative to the second column one. Is there a way, assuming I cannot change the order of the code that Column Two could float right relative to the first incarnation of column one.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column1">Column One</div>
    <div class="column1">Column One</div>
    <div class="column2">Column Two</div>
</div>

.container {
    width:400px;
}

.column1 {
    float:left;
    width: 260px;
    height:400px;
    background:red;
}

.column2 {
    float:right;
    width: 120px;
    height:400px;
    background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nya28329/5/

Comment: Would would the desired result look like?

Comment: @j08691 Like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/nya28329/8/

Comment: In your second fiddle (the 8th one), as opposed to the first one (the 5th), the second `column1` is actually "Column Two", the third column. This is confusing and makes it hard to figure out what you want.

Comment: @MrLister The second one is to show you what I'm trying to achieve with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The float property is a bit tricky.

As you can see, in the image i have added, the second-column1 element occupies the space beside the 1st-column1 element(i.e,the pink rectangular box). But, as its size cannot is large (i.e, 260px <  container-width(400px)) it appears below the 1st-column element.

This is the reason, why the column2 element appears below. Because that particular space have been occupied by the 2nd-Column1 element.
(it is similar to a relatively positioned element. i.e, it occupies space but it appears / positioned in another place)

hence, what you are trying to achieve cannot be done without changing the html